# Why glibc2.23 change struct sockaddr_storage?

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6, glibc

I checked the git log as https://patchwork.sourceware.org/patch/12453/. This modification seems to fix an issue on a specific platform.
But I don't understand why to swap __ss_align and __ss_padding in struct sockaddr_storage.
The Qualcomm platform I'm now developing on has lots of typecast as follows.

```
struct sockaddr_storage prefix_addr

(struct sockaddr_in6 *)&(prefix_addr)->sin6_addr.s6_addr
```

On our Cortex A7 platform, struct alignment are as follows:

Before glibc2.23:

```
struct sockaddr_in6
{
    sin6_family;   //0th byte
    sin6_port;     //2nd byte
    sin6_flowinfo; //4th byte
    sin6_addr;     //8th byte
};


struct sockaddr_storage
{
    ss_family;    //0th byte
    __ss_align;   //4th byte
    __ss_padding; //8th byte
};
```

After glibc2.23:

```
struct sockaddr_storage
{
    ss_family;    //0th byte
    __ss_padding; //2nd byte
    __ss_align;   //124th byte
};
```

glibc changed struct sockaddr_storage, but struct sockaddr_in6 is not changed, so this modification would cause many alignment issues on our platform, which lead getting IPV6 addresses errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the reply from the Florian:

> On 09/01/2017 12:07 PM, honan li wrote:
>
> > define SASTORAGE_DATA(addr)    (addr).__ss_padding
> >
> > typedef struct qcmap_cm_nl_prefix_info_s {
> >       boolean prefix_info_valid;
> >       unsigned char prefix_len;
> >       unsigned int mtu;
> >       struct sockaddr_storage prefix_addr;
> >       struct ifa_cacheinfo          cache_info;
> >     } qcmap_cm_nl_prefix_info_t;
> >
> > void QCMAP_Backhaul::GetIPV6PrefixInfo(char *devname,
> >                                            qcmap_cm_nl_prefix_info_t
> >     *ipv6_prefix_info)
> >     {
> >       struct sockaddr_in6 *sin6 = NULL;
> >
> > ...
> >
> > sin6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)&ipv6_prefix_info->prefix_addr;
> >       memcpy(SASTORAGE_DATA(ipv6_prefix_info->prefix_addr),
> >              RTA_DATA(rta),
> >              sizeof(sin6->sin6_addr));
> >       ...
> >     }
>
> Currently publicly available here:
>
> https://github.com/Bigcountry907/HTC_a13_vzw_Kernel/blob/master/vendor/qcom/proprietary/data/mobileap_v2/server/src/QCMAP_ConnectionManager.cpp#L3658
>
> I would expect applications do something like this instead:
>
> struct sockaddr_in6 sin6;   memset (&sin6, 0, sizeof (sin6));
>   sin6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;   memcpy (&sin6.sin6_addr, RTA_DATA
>   (rta), sizeof (sin6.sin6_addr));   memcpy
>   (&ipv6_prefix_info->prefix_addr, &sin6, sizeof (sin6));
>
> This avoids any aliasing issues and a dependency on the internals of
>   struct sockaddr_storage (which is only intended as a way to allocate a
>   generic struct sockaddr of sufficient size and alignment).  It also
>   initializes the other components of the socket address (such as the
>   port number and flow label).
>
> Thanks, Florian

Also refer to:
https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=ptSC4LpwGA0C&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=alignment+sufficient&source=bl&ots=Kt0BQhjiMt&sig=HTUbm2bzVNSoMxNX98EMzORFc30&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP78iMoovWAhVLipQKHYFdCxcQ6AEIQzAF#v=onepage&q=alignment%20sufficient&f=false

Conclusion is Qualcomm's usage of sockaddr_storage is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the change in glibc that generates alignment warnings: this change has no effect on the source code you show.

On the contrary, I think Qualcomm is using clang, and beginning with clang 4.x, there is a new alignment warning that I've seen generating **false positive** warning about alignements, depending on the way you write your code: `-Waddress-of-packed-member`.

You should check if the clang version you are using has changed, since glibc changed. If this is the case, this could certainly explain your problem.

Using a temporary variable makes those warning disappear.

instead of making a call like:

```
my_function(((struct sockaddr_in6 *)&prefix_addr)->sin6_addr.s6_addr)
```

just write:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 p = *(struct sockaddr_in6 *) &prefix_addr;
my_function(p.sin6_addr.s6_addr);
```

This may avoid alignment warnings.

Comment: Hi, Alexandre, 
Sorry that I didn't made myself clear enough. What I'm now encountering is not compiling warnings. It's a fault. As IPV6 address is always kept in sockaddr_storage.__ss_padding, when we expected to get IPV6 address like 1111:2222:3333:4444:5555:6666:7777:8888 as before, on glibc2.23 in fact we got 2233:3344:4455:5566:6677:7788:88xx:xxxx.

Comment: OK, the problem is that using `sockaddr_storage.__ss_padding` to access the address was an effective trick but undocumented and based on a specific implementation. Since it was not in the specs, people made changes and finally, you get errors. The only way you can avoid errors is to use the typecast you have written at the beginning of your question, because it is the only way to be compliant with the specs. If you look at the Berkeley implementation, you will see yet another way to add padding inside this structure: https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/sys/_sockaddr_storage.h